# Why do some github npm packages not fully install?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to install [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff) from its [github repo](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff) using this command:

```
npm install --save github:kpdecker/jsdiff
```

It looked like it went okay, because the `diff` folder got created inside `node_modules` but it didn't contain the `lib` or `dist` folders and none of its dependencies got installed. These were the only files that get copied:

```
runtime.js
release-notes.md
package.json
README.md
LICENSE
CONTRIBUTING.md
```

However, the command above works perfectly when installing other packages. For example:

```
npm install --save github:visionmedia/express
```

So, what am I missing. Is there some other command that I'm supposed to run to complete the installation of `jsdiff`?

Comment: https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/issues/134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package needs a build step (see the [gruntfile.js](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L141)). So the artifacts (the files that will be generated at the build step wont be checked in the versioning system - git - you wont have to deal with them in your diffs and merge).

Also check out the [.npmignore](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/blob/master/.npmignore) file.

Comment: Gotcha. I get it now. Thanks!